# SSRS Group Formatting

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, ssrs-2016

Building a report and I am trying to get specific formatting of a group I have.  I have a list of tasks with times and these fall under specific days.  I want to group these by the days so that the report shows me the information as such.  I have set up a row group and I have this all displaying nearly the way I want it but I want to get it better.  Here is what I am seeing right now:

```
|Monday|      |      |
|------|------|------|
|      |Task 1|9a-3p |
|      |Task 2|3p-4p |
```

What I would like to see is this:

```
|Monday|     |
|------|-----|
|Task 1|9a-3p|
|Task 2|3p-4p|
```

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

after some playing around, I was able to get this to work by doing a parent group inside a parent group under Row Groups.  Once I did that, I was able to copy over the title bar from the first parent group into the cell right above my first column data, collapsed and hid the first two columns (parent group headers) and it worked.